# How to get the uri which was used but threw UriFormatException?

Tags: c#, webview, exception, uri, uwp

I am using webview and at one point it navigates to URi Scheme and I subscribe to an event called UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified.

But when I check its event argument it says that the uri could not be parsed, how to get the uri that it tried to parse[image]

Comment: If all fails, you can always try to use `Reflection` to retrieve the private field used to generated the `Uri`.

Comment: UriFormatException is thrown when accessing Uri property :(

Comment: Don't observe the property. Try to find the field that is used to create the `Uri`.

Comment: Could you please post your URI so can I have a test?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT It looks like this :
ticketurlscheme://{"status":"FAILED", "transaction_id":"asdasdasdasdasd", "result":"FAILED"} ....
Because this scheme is not valid (cuz it is json) it throws exception, but I need to get this string to parse json myself but I cant get it

Answer (score 0):

Since, there is no source code of UWP floating around and I don't have access to sdk, I will show a method to do it, instead of giving a solution directly.

I would assume the EventArgs would look somewhat like this :

```
public sealed class SomeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly string address;
    public Uri Uri => new Uri(address);

    public SomeEventArgs(string address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

---

```
// If the address is not formatted property, 
// trying to get the `Uri` will cause an exception to be thrown: 
var e = new SomeEventArgs("qwe'1231[e);");

// But, we can use to reflection to find out what private fields are,
// and possibly dug out something interesting
var fields = typeof(SomeEventArgs).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Select(x => new { x.Name, x.FieldType });

// Say if you find something interesting, like 'address',
// you can retrieve its value like this
var address = typeof(SomeEventArgs).GetField("address", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(e);
```

Comment: it has 0 private fields  fields , i think this is because of exception :(